# Remove all cordova-sqlite-storage values when logging out the ionic3 app?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm currently working on ionic 3 app and used https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage plugin. Now I'm working on the log out. I couldn't found how to remove all data that are stored in the database while logging out the app.

Comment: There is api [`clear()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage#clear-) in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing and injecting storage I needed to use the following method by using the clear method.

```
logOut() {
    this.storage.clear().then((data) => {
      console.log('In promise of clear the data ', data);
      this.navCtrl.push(SignInPage);

    });
```